# How to integrate Ember.JS and Keycloak SSO system

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-sign-on, keycloak

My question is quite simple : does anybody know how to integrate Ember.JS and Keycloak (the SSO system) ? We currently face a problem using the Keycloak JS Bower library (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-js-bower) to redirect users to Keycloak own login page, and to generally integrate Ember.JS with Keycloak. Our problems are :

Double page reload on page reloading,

401 unauthorized HTTP code on login to the Ember App.

Thanks for your (precious) support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use script JS:
Check that you have script in your keycloak: `https://yourdoamin.com/auth/js/keycloak.js`

If you have, add this code to your login page:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://yourdoamin.com/auth/js/keycloak.js"></script>
    <script>
        var keycloak = Keycloak({
            "realm": "relam_name",
            "url": "https://yourdomain.com/auth",
            "ssl-required": "external",
            "resource": "client_id",
            "verify-token-audience": true,
            "credentials": {
                "secret": "secret_code"
            },
            "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
            "confidential-port": 0,
            "policy-enforcer": {},
            "onLoad":'login-required',
            "clientId": "client_id"
        });

        var keycloak = Keycloak();
        keycloak.init().success(function(authenticated) {
            console.log(keycloak);
            alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
        }).error(function() {
            alert('failed to initialize');
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

In `console.log(keycloak);` Keycloak return token and other information about user.

More info:

[Keycloak JavaScript API to get current logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019521/keycloak-javascript-api-to-get-current-logged-in-user)

[JavaScript Adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter)

[MicroProfile JWT Authentication with Keycloak and React](https://rieckpil.de/howto-microprofile-jwt-authentication-with-keycloak-and-react/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ember cli addons that deal with Keycloak and Ember integration:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-keycloak

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-keycloak-auth