# Keycloak adapter not able retrieve current username from windows AD logged-in user

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am using keycloak server version 10.0.2 and keycloak js version 10.0.2 and have created a identity provider OpenID connect and filled-in the required fields. I was able to connect to AD and sync user to keycloak after logged into AD. I have been given a windows machine with active directory username and password.Once logged-in to windows, I am logged into AD, but the problem is neither in chrome nor in firefox, gets the currently logged in windows AD user for single sign on, The code I have is given in this link:
[Keycloak JavaScript API to get current logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019521/keycloak-javascript-api-to-get-current-logged-in-user)

Please help

Regards

Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is we need to install chrome browser plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windows-accounts/ppnbnpeolgkicgegkbkbjmhlideopiji?hl=en  for browser syncing with Azure active directory. For firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/windows-sso will help.

Cool stuff works

Regards
Kris