# Object is not a constructor in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, keycloak

I am writing a React Native app.

I am trying to authenticate using Keycloak.

I am using the `react-keycloak` library.

Here's my code:

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
import { KeycloakProvider } from "react-keycloak";
import keycloak_config from "./config/keycloak.json";
const keycloak = new Keycloak(keycloak_config);
```

This is throwing the following error:

[image: Object not a constructor]

However, this is quite literally how the docs for this library suggest to use it, and I have tested it previously in other projects and it works fine.

What is going on here? Is it a react native issue specifically?

I was asked for keycloak.json, so here it is:

keycloak.json:

```
{
  "resource": "client-name",
  "realm": "realm-name",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "clientId": "client-name",
  "url": "https://example-domain-here.com/auth",
  "auth-server-url": "https://example-domain-here.com/auth",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "alphanumeric-hash-from-keycloak"
  }
}
```

Comment: One possible solution might be related to allowSyntheticDefaultImports?

Comment: Post `keycloak.json` also.

Comment: @ravibagul91 posted it

Comment: That's the node.js adapter. Wouldn't I be using the pure JS adapter?

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter - here, as opposed to your link

Comment: And that file IS the file from the admin console.

Comment: I am also having the "Object is not constructor" error when trying to use your syntax with an object with store as the first value

Comment: I actually think that this library possibly cannot be used with React Native

Comment: @CecilRodriguez You can loged in user using keycloak script. Look on my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57817462/6678345

Comment: I’m not sure how this solves my problem. I’m likely going to have to fork the library for RN